# How can we get the mobilenumber of a user in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile

Does anyone know how to retrieve the mobile number of a O365 user? I have queried both the user profile and regular user object and the MobileNumber property is empty.

When I go to delve I can see that the user infact to have a mobile number on his profile. Based on my research it seems that this property is not stored in the user profile and thereby not available through the GetPropertiesFor method.

So, how can we retrieve this information?

Answer (score 2):

The Mobile Phone property is not mapped to the CellPhone by default. And there is no OOB method to configure this.
For the Mobile Phone, we need to get the property value from AAD and then update the user profile property value in SharePoint.

For example:

```
Import-Module MSOnline
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell

# add SharePoint CSOM libraries
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll'

# Defaults
$spoAdminUrl = "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com"
$overwriteExistingSPOUPAValue = "False"

# Get credentials of account that is AzureAD Admin and SharePoint Online Admin
$credential = Get-Credential

Try {
    # Connect to AzureAD
    Connect-MsolService -Credential $credential

    # Get credentials for SharePointOnline
    $spoCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credential.GetNetworkCredential().Username, (ConvertTo-SecureString $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password -AsPlainText -Force))
    $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($spoAdminUrl)
    $ctx.Credentials = $spoCredentials
    $spoPeopleManager = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager($ctx)

    # Get all AzureAD Users
    $AzureADUsers = Get-MSolUser -All

    ForEach ($AzureADUser in $AzureADUsers) {

        $mobilePhone = $AzureADUser.MobilePhone
        $targetUPN = $AzureADUser.UserPrincipalName.ToString()
        $targetSPOUserAccount = ("i:0#.f|membership|" + $targetUPN)

        # Check to see if the AzureAD User has a MobilePhone specified
        if (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($mobilePhone))) {
            # Get the existing value of the SPO User Profile Property CellPhone
            $targetUserCellPhone = $spoPeopleManager.GetUserProfilePropertyFor($targetSPOUserAccount, "CellPhone")
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

            $userCellPhone = $targetUserCellPhone.Value

            # If target property is empty let's populate it
            if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($userCellPhone)) {
                $targetspoUserAccount = ("i:0#.f|membership|" + $AzureADUser.UserPrincipalName.ToString())
                $spoPeopleManager.SetSingleValueProfileProperty($targetspoUserAccount, "CellPhone", $mobilePhone)
                $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            }
            else {
                # Target property is not empty
                # Check to see if we're to overwrite existing property value
                if ($overwriteExistingSPOUPAValue -eq "True") {
                    $targetspoUserAccount = ("i:0#.f|membership|" + $AzureADUser.UserPrincipalName.ToString())
                    $spoPeopleManager.SetSingleValueProfileProperty($targetspoUserAccount, "CellPhone", $mobilePhone)
                    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                }
                else {
                    # Not going to overwrite existing property value
                    Write-Output "Target SPO UPA CellPhone is not empty for $targetUPN and we're to preserve existing properties"
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            # AzureAD User MobilePhone is empty, nothing to do here
            Write-Output "AzureAD MobilePhone Property is Null or Empty for $targetUPN)"
        }
    }
}
Catch {
    [Exception]
}
```

Refer to: https://www.tishenko.com/sync-mobile-phone-from-aad-to-sharepoint-online/

A similar issue:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_manage/mobile-and-office-field-in-active-directory-sync/c200690f-e886-4820-8947-bf538a346861